# Pentaho Data Integration Switch/Case

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I have an excel imput for all the data I want added to my database. Have over 100 rows with the following information: category name, product name, product description, stock, restock, price.

I have linked the imput to a database lookup to check if the category is already in the database and return null if not. Everything up to here works fine.

I linked the lookup to a switch/case and if the value is null, it it send to "add the category" (table output), if not, it goes to "add product"(table output). Unfortunately, as the database is new, the categories are not added so all of them are set to null. As the information gets to the "add category" part, the duplicates create an error (Duplicate entry 'GST' for key 'name_UNIQUE'.

How can I force the switch/case to only take one of the duplicates with that name and send it to add the category and the rest to just add the products in that category?

The category name must be unique. Not sure if i covered everything here so feel free to ask questions. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Not clear with the question but have you tried unique raws step?

Comment: I did it earlier and it worked just fine. Now however, it sends all the rows with null return value (as no category was yet added to the database). I fixed my issue by adding the categories myself and letting it just add the rest. It's a temporary fix however and I can't figure out why two days earlier it worked fine and now it's not :\, same schema, same everything. 

I can try with unique row indeed. That way I can bypass the look up and as the category is first, it will "identify" each category and avoid duplicates. Thanks, will let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Worked out fine - if you wish to answer it. :)